# Software to monitor forum posts

Tags: forum

Is there software that monitors the activity of forum posts across multiple sites and allows users to easily see when there are updates to those posts?  Like suppose you have posts that you're following on multiple sites.  You want to be notified when there is a new reply.  So you paste the URL of those threads into this software and it starts to monitor them for you.

Operating System: Linux (preferred) or Windows if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many forums come with a feed link. For example, if you scroll down on this page you can find it in the bottom right corner:

[image]

Right click and choose `Copy link address` or the equivalent option in your browser. You can paste that into any newsfeed application. [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird) and [QuiteRSS](http://quiterss.org/) are two examples of many.

QuiteRSS also provides notifications and feed count in the tray icon:
[image]

Note that in [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) you can simply click the feed link next to the orange icon instead of copying the address, and it will automatically ask you to add a "live bookmark" as shown below. You can either add it to firefox bookmarks, or choose an external feed application from the drop down menu

[image]